# Excel treatement of datatypes and SSIS imports

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an excel file that has a column that is showing as number. It has a dollar figure i.e: 87,512.97.  However, when I import it to Sql Server using the import wizard, the field is loaded as a date.  Why is this happening?!

I know how I can fix this using conversions, etc, but how can this possibly be detected and accounted for before running into an error?  In my ssis package I naturally saw this field as a number field and treated it as such.

My question is also general to all fields in excel files that need to be imported.  For example, I have other date fields that are store as excel date serial numbers, some get detected as string (failing on conversion to date data types), others get detected as floats (allowing for implicit conversion to date datatype).  Why does this happen and how can you account for both possibilities?

Comment: A) Save to another format (Excel is terrible), B) Set your field types (by column) in Excel before importing, but this only works maybe 20% of the time C) Save to another format

Comment: While I was away, I thought of another option D) Save to another format.

Comment: Jacob is right. Excel imports will eventually break because you cannot define data types. SSIS will guess based on the first "so many" records which will eventually end up being null and it will guess text and your numbers and dates will blow up the load.